# Calculate sum and multiply its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calculating the sum of `a` and `b` and putting it in text box named `sum`.

After I enter a number in number text box, it should calculate the `final = sum * number`.

```
<input type="text" class="txt_1_0" name="a" />
<input type="text" class="txt_1_0" name="b" />
<input type="text" id="sum" name="sum" />
<input type="text" class="number" name="number" />
<input type="text" class="final" name="final" />
```

I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".txt_1_0").change(function() {
        var total = 0.00;
        var textbox3 = 0.00;    // this gonna be your third textbox
        $(".txt_1_0").each(function() {
            total += parseFloat(this.value) / 5;
        });

        textbox3 = $("#sum").val((total).toFixed(2));
    });
 });
```

How do I get the number value and calculate `final`?

Comment: why would you divide it by 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't actually added any function that would do the final calculation. So to multiply the `sum` (subtotal) with `number`, do the following:

```
$(".number").change(function () {
    var final = $("#sum").val() * $(this).val();
    $('.final').val(final);
});
```

**[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Y6w/)** - note that I have removed the division by 5 from your previous function as it didn't make sense from the the way your question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use keyup event with this jQuery code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/NLbfx/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){
        var a=parseFloat($('.txt_1_0:first').val())
        var b=parseFloat($('.txt_1_0:last').val())
        if(a && b){$('#sum').val(a+b)}
        var number=$('.number').val()
        if(number){
            $('.final').val($('#sum').val()*number)
            }
        })
})
</script>
```